# SQL Server : merging into table without duplicates when it has an identity number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to conduct either an insert into a table (can drop and re-create it) or a merge for a table as part of a regular update. This update needs to not result in duplicates in the target table.

My goal is to update my table from a raw table with only those new rows which would not be duplicates.

My problem is that the raw data set has an identity assigned to it so that effectively every row is unique including identity but not unique excluding identity.

Is there anyway for me to conduct a duplicate check while ignoring the identity (primary key).

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Sorry it's in Microsoft Sequel Server Management studio

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may build a hash value from all relevant data and use it as a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidx_pid
ON Table(val1, val2, val3);

Create table index, it will not accept any duplicates of the rows within the scope of the columns specified

Comment: As i've got a primary key it is saying it is not able to create it:
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'T1' and the index name 'u_index_T1_TEMP'. The duplicate key value is (1000040192, 26, 10, 2).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the identity column, you can do a group by:

```
SELECT max(r.ID) as ID,r.col1,r.col2,r.col3
FROM rawTable r
GROUP BY r.col1,r.col2,r.col3
```

If you want to completely leave out the duplicate rows you can add a HAVING:

```
SELECT max(r.ID) as ID,r.col1,r.col2,r.col3
FROM rawTable r
GROUP BY r.col1,r.col2,r.col3
HAVING COUNT(r.ID) = 1
```

Comment: The problem would mean that i'm not able to carry the identity column forward and I need to do that to join it with other tables.

Comment: Then do a group by and add a MAX(myIdentityColumn)